# Django: From List of ForeignKey-Parents: get the on with the newest Child

Tags: python, django, django-models

is there a way to get, from a list of ForeignKey-Parents, the one which got the newest Child?
For example:

```
class parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(*)

class child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(parent, *)
```

Now, given a list of parents, i want to get the parent, which had a child added last. Is there an easy way to do that in Django?

Thanks for the Answers!

Comment: Strictly speaking you can not rely on the primary key to know what was last added. You better add a timestamp for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not rely on the primary key to know what was last added. You better add a timestamp for this. So you might want to change your model to:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then you can obtain the parent with the most recent child with:

```
Parent.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_parents).order_by('-child__created').first()
```

This will return a `Parent` object if such parent exists, and `None` otherwise.

If adding a timestamp is *not* an option, you can try to work with the primary key, but a database does *not* per se distributes primary key values in a certain order:

```
# does not per se works

Parent.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_parents).order_by('-child__pk').first()
```

Comment: Adding a created-field is an option. Does this still work, when a parent has multiple children?

Comment: @Sarius: yes, since we JOIN on the `Children` table, and thus the child that is the most recent (highest timestamp) will occur first with its parent.